# React ChartJS 2 : Get data on clicking the chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I found many other questions on StackOverflow as well as GitHub but none of them worked for me...

I have a graph built using ChartJS. When I click on any of the bars(orange, green or red) I want to get the corresponding value. Is there any way to achieve this?
The npm package I am using is react-chartjs-2.
It has 2 props that I found may be helpful but don't know how to use it in this case. They are **getElementsAtEvent** and **onElementsClick**. These props when used gives tons of data except the value of the bar that I just clicked into.

This is how I import the component

`import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";`

This is how I use the component

```
<Bar
  data={barData}
  height={275}
  options={{
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  }}
/>;
```

And the variable barData is as follows:

```
const barData = {
  labels: [
    "04-07-2020",
    "05-07-2020",
    "06-07-2020",
    "07-07-2020",
    "08-07-2020",
    "09-07-2020",
    "10-07-2020",
  ],

  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Cases",
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: "#ffc299",
      borderColor: "#cc5200",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#ed873e",
      hoverBorderColor: "#e35f00",
      data: [673165, 697413, 719664, 742417, 767296, 793802, 820916],
    },
    {
      label: "Recovered",
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: "#b3ffb3",
      borderColor: "#00ff00",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#55cf72",
      hoverBorderColor: "#2c9c46",
      data: [409083, 424433, 439934, 456831, 476378, 495513, 515386],
    },
    {
      label: "Deaths",
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: "#de8078",
      borderColor: "#fa6457",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#d73627",
      hoverBorderColor: "#ff4636",
      data: [19268, 19693, 20159, 20642, 21129, 21604, 22123],
    },
  ],
};
```

This is the graph

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: For the way you have structured your data in `barData`; the entire element is clicked on and not just a specific bar. It returns an array of length 3 for the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your data is structured in a certain way, when a bar is clicked, an array of size 3 is returned as `elem`. You can extract the data from there based on your requirement.

Using `onElementsClick`:

```
<Bar
  data={barData}
  height={275}
  onElementsClick={elem => {
    var data = barData.datasets[elem[0]._datasetIndex].data;
    console.log("Cases", data[elem[0]._index]);

    data = barData.datasets[elem[1]._datasetIndex].data;
    console.log("Recovered", data[elem[1]._index]);

    data = barData.datasets[elem[2]._datasetIndex].data;
    console.log("Deaths", data[elem[2]._index]);
  }}
  options={{
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  }}
/>;
```

`elem` is populated with the clicked element. You might need to tweak this code a bit to achieve exactly what you're looking for depending on what you want to do with that data. Sandbox in comment.

Comment: I already mentioned it in the question that I get a lot of data if I console the elem in onElementsClick.And also mentioned that I am not getting the data that I am looking for. 
Sorry but this doesn't solve my issue and it is not what I wanted...
Please read the question. It is clearly mentioned that onElementsClick didnot work for me...

Comment: @RahulRavi I went through the pains of fixing your code. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lichterman-f8yof?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is the sandbox too.

Comment: I was not being rude brother. Sorry if I was rude rather I was frustrated because of this thing. Thank you it worked like charm and I am accepting this answer. Thanks for the help. You saved my day... I have been searching for it for the past 2 days.

Comment: "ParthShah  I see you used `onElementsClick` and your comment solved an issue i had. I searched this `onElementsClick` on the docs and can't find it. Where did you find this information? Thank You.

Comment: `onElementsClick` is not apart of the current Typescript files for ReactJS, not sure where that comes from

Comment: It's a method implemented in chart.js

Answer (score 3):

You can define an `onClick` function inside the chart options.

```
onClick: (event, elements) => {
  const chart = elements[0]._chart;
  const element = chart.getElementAtEvent(event)[0];
  const dataset = chart.data.datasets[element._datasetIndex];
  const xLabel = chart.data.labels[element._index];
  const value = dataset.data[element._index];
  console.log(dataset.label + " at " + xLabel + ": " + value);
}
```

Please have a look at your amended code in the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-zbalyu?file=index.jsY).

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that onElementsClick is deprecated in chart-js-2 ver.>3
You cat try this:

```
<Bar
  data={data}
  options={options}
  getElementAtEvent={(elements, event) => {
    if (event.type === "click" && elements.length) {
      console.log(elements[0]);
    }
  }}
/>
```